# Re-position div on mobile with CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout that is several blocks of copy with an accompanying image ([link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y74tfde/)).

```
<div class="story-body">

    <div class="body-copy">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus iaculis felis, molestie tincidunt est hendrerit vel. Aenean mattis convallis malesuada. Donec nec risus sem. Mauris mi urna, dictum in pulvinar vehicula, rutrum in elit. Sed pulvinar, elit sit amet sollicitudin imperdiet, mauris velit sollicitudin velit, nec lacinia dui massa vitae tellus. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="regular-photo">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    </div>


    <div class="body-copy">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus iaculis felis, molestie tincidunt est hendrerit vel. Aenean mattis convallis malesuada. Donec nec risus sem. Mauris mi urna, dictum in pulvinar vehicula, rutrum in elit. Sed pulvinar, elit sit amet sollicitudin imperdiet, mauris velit sollicitudin velit, nec lacinia dui massa vitae tellus. </p>
    </div>

    <div class="regular-photo">
         <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
    </div>

</div>
```

It displays perfectly on desktop — the image lines up next to the top of the accompanying copy block. The problem is, on mobile, the images show up after the body copy sections which, makes sense, considering I organized the HTML that way.

```
.story-body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.body-copy {
    justify-self: center;
    max-width: 80%;
}

.regular-photo {
justify-self: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .story-body {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    }
    .regular-photo {
    justify-self: center;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to position the `.regular-photo` divs before the `.body-copy` divs on mobile without having to reorganize the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some little refactoring with your code. Excuse me. But here is the solution. You can use `order property` with the children of the class containing `display: grid`

```css
.story-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  justify-self: center;
}

.story-body p {
  justify-self: center;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.regular-photo {
  justify-self: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .story-body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .photo1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .p1 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .photo2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .p2 {
    order: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="story-body">
  <p class="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus iaculis felis, molestie tincidunt est hendrerit vel. Aenean mattis convallis malesuada. Donec nec risus sem. Mauris mi urna, dictum in pulvinar vehicula, rutrum in elit. Sed pulvinar,
    elit sit amet sollicitudin imperdiet, mauris velit sollicitudin velit, nec lacinia dui massa vitae tellus. </p>
  <div class="regular-photo photo1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </div>

  <p class="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus iaculis felis, molestie tincidunt est hendrerit vel. Aenean mattis convallis malesuada. Donec nec risus sem. Mauris mi urna, dictum in pulvinar vehicula, rutrum in elit. Sed pulvinar,
    elit sit amet sollicitudin imperdiet, mauris velit sollicitudin velit, nec lacinia dui massa vitae tellus. </p>
  <div class="regular-photo photo2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know you could explicitly order elements. More simplistic and quicker than defining a ton of grid areas. Cheers!

Comment: I am glad. I should have explained it like you did - "you could explicitly order elements" Please +1 the answer so someone else can find the same conclusion. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly declare `grid-template-areas` and place each div accordingly.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03hk5L2p/1/)

```css
.story-body {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
      grid-auto-flow: row;
    }
    
    .body-copy {
      justify-self: center;
      max-width: 80%;
    }
    
    .regular-photo {
      justify-self: left;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .story-body {
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-areas: "image" 
                             "text"
                             "image2"
                             "text2";
      }
      
      .regular-photo {
        justify-self: center;
      }
      
      .story-body > div:nth-of-type(1) {
        grid-area: text;
      }
      .story-body > div:nth-of-type(2) {
        grid-area: image;
      }
      .story-body > div:nth-of-type(3) {
        grid-area: text2;
      }
      .story-body > div:nth-of-type(4) {
        grid-area: image2;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="story-body">
  <div class="body-copy">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus iaculis felis, molestie tincidunt est hendrerit vel. Aenean mattis convallis malesuada. Donec nec risus sem. Mauris mi urna, dictum in pulvinar vehicula, rutrum in elit. Sed pulvinar,
      elit sit amet sollicitudin imperdiet, mauris velit sollicitudin velit, nec lacinia dui massa vitae tellus. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="regular-photo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </div>

  <div class="body-copy">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec dapibus iaculis felis, molestie tincidunt est hendrerit vel. Aenean mattis convallis malesuada. Donec nec risus sem. Mauris mi urna, dictum in pulvinar vehicula, rutrum in elit. Sed pulvinar,
      elit sit amet sollicitudin imperdiet, mauris velit sollicitudin velit, nec lacinia dui massa vitae tellus. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="regular-photo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
  </div>
</div>
```